# Creating n number of Student structures based on user input

Tags: c++, input, structure

I created a structure called student in a source module as follows:

```
struct Student
{
std::string gradeOption;
std::string name;
unsigned int id;
};
```

In the main.cpp source file, I am meant to read user input which follows these rules:

a positive integer on the first line, stating the number of students
There will be n number of lines, each in this format: an id number followed by a space, a grade option followed by a space, the student's name followed by a space. Any character after the grade option is considered to be the students name. 
Here is an an example

```
5
123 G Tom Cruise
234 G Boo Scary
345 G Jane Student
456 P Joe Student
567 G Too-Many Courses
```

I cannot figure out how to create n number of structures. My problem is I cannot figure out how to name them. If I were to do a while loop until i = 5 I still have no way of coming up with names without overwriting the same structure. Also, should I be creating these structures in the main.cpp file or the structure.cpp file?

I also tried using an array by putting the id as the array name and making it an array of strings

```
void createStudentArray(int numStudents, int size)
for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
std::string arrayName;
std::string gradeOption, studentName
std::string* arrayName = std::string[size];
```

Comment: Take a look into the topic *array*.

Comment: I've tried to do that but run into the same problem. I tried using the id as the name of the array and making it an array of strings

Comment: Pls show the code you tried.

Comment: You can use `std::vector<Student>` to access structures by index or `std::map<unsigned in, Student>` to access them by id for example...

Comment: I added it @progsource

Comment: @stas I am not allowed to use vector

Comment: If you're not allowed to use any kind of container, then what about `Student* students = new Student[count];`? Then access them by index `students[2]`.

Comment: I've modified my code (removed `std::vector`).

Comment: @stas an array of Students seems towork thnks!

Answer (score 1):

I've made a sample code. Maybe it will be useful.

```
#include <string>
//#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Student {
    std::string gradeOption;
    std::string name;
    unsigned int id;
};

// this tells how to read student from console
void operator>>(std::istream& is, Student& s) {
    is >> s.id >> s.gradeOption >> s.name;
}

// this tells how to write student to console
void operator<<(std::ostream& os, Student& s) {
    os << s.id << " " << s.gradeOption << " " << s.name << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    using namespace std;

    // here will be placed a number of students to read
    size_t count;

//  // container for students
//  std::vector<Student> students;

//  // last read student
//  Student student;

    cout << "enter count:" << endl;
    cin >> count;
    cout << "reading " << count << " students" << endl;

//  while (count--) {
//      cin >> student;
//      students.push_back(student);
//  }
//
//  for (Student& s: students) {
//      cout << s;
//  }

    Student* students = new Student[count];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        cin >> students[i];
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        cout << students[i];
    }

    delete[] students;

    return 0;
}
```